# LINQ SELECT TAKE 1 EACH ROW

Tags: c#, linq

How can i select take 1 each data in column in linq that only return 1 row. Because when i put .Take(1) only 1 row result will appear but i want to have 2 row result with different entry

to make it clear here's what i mean [image]

in c# here's my query

```
using (PharmacyDBEntities entities = new PharmacyDBEntities())
        {
            var positem = (from a in entities.POSEntries.Take(1)
                          where a.Invoice.AccountID == authLogin.userid && a.Invoice.InvoiceStatusID == 1
                          select new
                          {
                              a.Item.ItemCode,
                              a.Item.Name,
                              Quantity = (from b in entities.POSEntries where b.Invoice.AccountID == authLogin.userid && b.Invoice.InvoiceStatusID == 1 select b).Count(),
                              a.Item.SellingPrice
                          }).ToList();
            gcItemList.DataSource = positem;
        }
```

And the result 
[image]

Is there any suggestion guys? will make big help to me. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you want Distinct() instead of Take(1)? Something along these lines:

```
var positem = (from a in entities.POSEntries
    where a.Invoice.AccountID == authLogin.userid && a.Invoice.InvoiceStatusID == 1
                      select new
                      {
                          a.Item.ItemCode,
                          a.Item.Name,
                          Quantity = (from b in entities.POSEntries where b.Invoice.AccountID == authLogin.userid && b.Invoice.InvoiceStatusID == 1 select b).Count(),
                          a.Item.SellingPrice
                      }).Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Linq `GroupBy`

```
var positem = entities.POSEntries.Where( a=> a.Invoice.AccountID == authLogin.userid && a.Invoice.InvoiceStatusID == 1)
               .GroupBy(x=>x.Item.ItemCode).Select(g=> new {
                              g.Key,
                              g.First().Item.Name,
                              Quantity = g.Count(),
                              g.First().Item.SellingPrice
                          }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Take only returns first n elements. I think you need to try using the [Distinct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.